# generating sequential numbers using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This script generates random numbers.

However, I want to have sequential numbers (e.g. 100, 101, 102 etc.)

```
function randomNumber(len) {
  var randomNumber;
  var n = '';

  for(var count = 0; count < len; count++) {
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() *2);
    n += randomNumber.toString();
  }
  return n;

}

document.getElementById("inputID").value = randomNumber(5);
```

Comment: What would be wrong with a simple for loop starting at 100?

Comment: What are sequential random numbers?

Comment: how can it be random if it has to be sequential?

Comment: You only need one random to start with....then increment that in the loop

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a loop: Just start with whichever number you like (e.g. 100) and increment the number in the loop.

If you are not working in a loop and you have to increment the number based on an infrequent event, e.g. a user action in an online dialogue, you will have to save the last used number in a database and increment that one.

Here is an example for a serial starting with 1 in PHP: (Javascript won't do it here (in most cases) because this happens on the server ... But of course: You don't have to use PHP! This is merely an example.)

```
function getSerial ($dbh) {        
    $dbh->query('SELECT COALESCE(MAX(serial), 0) AS maxSerial  
                   FROM myTable');
    $row = $dbh->singleAssoc(); // a one-dimensional array is returned SINGLE
    if ( (bool)$dbh->rowCount() ) {  
        if ( $row['maxSerial']  <= 0 ) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return $row['maxSerial'] + 1;
        }
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```